Servo motors do not rotate constantly unlike the original Arduino code intended to
I want to move servo motors for loop without stopping! What is wrong?
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

int motors[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int degrees[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setPWMFreq(50);
  pwm.setOscillatorFrequency(27000000); 
  
  for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
    pwm.setPWM(i, 0, 150);   
  }
  
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
}

void joystick_val(int pin){
  Serial.print(pin);
  Serial.print("   ");  
}

void Move_motor(int motor, int degree, int int_val){
  if(int_val <= 1){
    degree += 5;
    if(degree > 180) degree = 180;
        
    int pul = map(degree,0,180,150,600);
    pwm.setPWM(motor, 0, pul);
  }
  
  else if(int_val >= 4){
    degree -= 5;
    if(degree < 0) degree = 0;
        
    int pul = map(degree,0,180,150,600);
    pwm.setPWM(motor, 0, pul);
  }
  
}

void loop() { 

  //int e = Serial.parseInt();
  int analogPin[] = {analogRead(A0), analogRead(A1), analogRead(A2), analogRead(A3)};
  int int_Pin[] = { map(analogPin[0], 0, 1023, 0, 5),
                    map(analogPin[1], 0, 1023, 0, 5),
                    map(analogPin[2], 0, 1023, 0, 5),
                    map(analogPin[3], 0, 1023, 0, 5)
                  };
  int Pin_amount = sizeof(analogPin)-4;
  
  Move_motor(motors[0], degrees[0], map(analogPin[0], 0, 1023, 0, 5));
  Move_motor(motors[1], degrees[1], map(analogPin[1], 0, 1023, 0, 5));
  Move_motor(motors[2], degrees[2], map(analogPin[2], 0, 1023, 0, 5));
  Move_motor(motors[3], degrees[3], map(analogPin[3], 0, 1023, 0, 5));


  for(int j=0; j<Pin_amount; j++){
    Serial.print(map(analogPin[j], 0, 1023, 0, 5));
    Serial.print("   "); 
  }       
  
  Serial.println("");
}

Originally the servo motors must keep rotating so long as the joystick connected to the motor is held, and only stop if the joystick is released. However, the servo motors stop after rotating for a split second instead of rotating continuously when the joystick is moved.
I tried using "for" loops and also tried changing the frequencies of PWM. What I want is make it so that the code functions the same without writing the Move_motor function four times. Thank you in advance.

Issues with regard to the servo motors not rotating properly:

When you change degree in Move_motor, it only changes the value locally.

It does not change the global array degrees, so the value of degree when Move_motor is called is always 0.

degree will only be 0 or 5


To fix this, we could pass degrees to Move_motor as a pointer.
But, there is much [needlessly] replicated code.
The best way to fix this is to use a single array of struct instead of many arrays indexed by the same value. This cleans up the code but also allows us to retain the degrees value between iterations.

Here is a refactored version. It is annotated:
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

// per-motor control
typedef struct mctl {
    int motidx;                         // motor index
    int apin;                           // AnalogRead port number

    int aval;                           // AnalogRead value
    int ival;                           // int of aval

    int degree;                         // current rotation
    int pul;                            // old motor pul value
} mctl_t;

#define NCTL        4
mctl_t controls[NCTL];

void
setup(void)
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pwm.begin();
    pwm.setPWMFreq(50);
    pwm.setOscillatorFrequency(27000000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        pwm.setPWM(i, 0, 150);

    Serial.setTimeout(10);

    int apin[] = { A0, A1, A2, A3 };
    for (mctl_t *mctl = &controls[0];  mctl < &controls[NCTL];  ++mctl) {
        int motidx = mctl - controls;
        mctl->motidx = motidx;
        mctl->apin = apin[motidx];
        mctl->pul = 0x7FFFFFFFF;
    }
}

void
joystick_val(int pin)
{
    Serial.print(pin);
    Serial.print("   ");
}

void
move_motor(mctl_t *mctl)
{
    int degree = mctl->degree;
    int setflg = 0;

    int int_val = map(mctl->aval, 0, 1023, 0, 5),

    do {
        if (int_val <= 1) {
            degree += 5;
            setflg = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (int_val >= 4) {
            degree -= 5;
            setflg = 1;
            break;
        }

        // do nothing???
    } while (0);

    if (degree > 180)
        degree = 180;
    if (degree < 0)
        degree = 0;

    do {
        if (! setflg)
            break;

        int pul = map(degree, 0, 180, 150, 600);

        // optional speedup: don't send value if hasn't changed since the last
        // time
        if (pul == mctl->pul)
            break;

        pwm.setPWM(mctl->motidx, 0, pul);

        // remember the value we just output
        mctl->pul = pul;
    } while (0);

    // save updated values
    mctl->degree = degree;
    mctl->ival = int_val;
}

void
loop(void)
{
    mctl_t *mctl;

    // grab all analog (joystick?) values quickly
    for (mctl = &controls[0];  mctl < &controls[NCTL];  ++mctl)
        mctl->aval = AnalogRead(mctl->apin);

    // change all motor values
    for (mctl = &controls[0];  mctl < &controls[NCTL];  ++mctl)
        move_motor(mctl);

    // show all values
    for (mctl = &controls[0];  mctl < &controls[NCTL];  ++mctl) {
        Serial.print(mctl->ival);
        Serial.print("   ");
    }
    Serial.println("");
}

